# How can I grey out weekends and holidays in AEM forms datepicker?

Tags: javascript, forms, aem

Can we grey out weekdays and weekends in AEM forms date picker

I have created a AEM form where I am using Datepicker widget.
I am trying to grey out the weekends and holidays in the AEM forms datepicker. Any suggestions I tried to use under Initialize method.
[Date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GngQr.png)